# WebBrowser control not displaying all images

Tags: c#, image, winforms, webbrowser-control

Case:

I'm creating a Windows Form Application and I'm having trouble displaying images on a webbrowser. About 10% of the images wont show up and "X"(not loaded) will appear, and I'm pretty sure it's caused by the documentCompleted code. I've tried 200 images without this method and they all did appear, and around 30 will not appear with the code.

Program:

I'm filling string array "allFiles" with all paths of the images i've chosen with a folderBrowserDialog.
Code:

```
browseButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
{
    //Creating and opening FolderBrowserDialog.
    using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
            fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

            //Check if chosen directory is valid.
            if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
            {
                     index = 0;
                     lblPath.Text = "Path: " + fbd.SelectedPath.ToString();
                     //Create array for all items in selected directories.
                     allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                     changeImage(false, false, false, false, false, false);
                     createLogFile();
             }
      }  
};
```

To loop through all the images and showing them in the webbrowser i use the following code:

```
BrowseRightButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
{
  changeImage(false, true, false, false, false, false);
};
```

This button calls method changeImage(updates global variable index) on click, see below for changeImage code:

```
private void changeImage(bool left, bool right, bool left10, bool right10, bool leftEnd, bool rightEnd)
{
 if (right == true)
 {
      index += 1;
      fileName = allFiles[index];
      webBrowser1.Navigate(fileName);
      updateLabel();

 }
 else if (left == true)
 {
      index -= 1;
      fileName = allFiles[index];
      webBrowser1.Navigate(fileName);
      updateLabel();
 }
 else if (left10 == true)
 {
      index -= 10;
      fileName = allFiles[index];
      webBrowser1.Navigate(fileName);
      updateLabel();
 }
 else if (right10 == true)
 {
      index += 10;
      fileName = allFiles[index];
      webBrowser1.Navigate(fileName);
      updateLabel();
 }
 else if (leftEnd == true)
 {
      index = 0;
      fileName = allFiles[index];
      webBrowser1.Navigate(fileName);
      updateLabel();
 }
 else if (rightEnd == true)
 {
      index = allFiles.Length - 1;
      fileName = allFiles[index];
      webBrowser1.Navigate(fileName);
      updateLabel();
 }
 else if (left == false && right == false && left10 == false && right10 == false && leftEnd == false && rightEnd == false)
 {
       fileName = allFiles[0];
       webBrowser1.Navigate(fileName);
 }
}
```

This method scales the image so it fits into the webBrowser:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (allFiles[index].EndsWith("JPG") || allFiles[index].EndsWith("PNG") || allFiles[index].EndsWith("jpg") || allFiles[index].EndsWith("png"))
    {
            webBrowser1.Document.Body.SetAttribute("scroll", "no");
            var img = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
                         .Cast<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault();
            var w = img.ClientRectangle.Width;
            var h = img.ClientRectangle.Height;
            img.Style = string.Format("{0}: 100%", w > h ? "Width" : "Height");
        }      
}
```

Image of me getting the "X":

[image]

OneDrive link which contains 60 images, and a GIF(at the end of the OneDrive folder) with me testing it and failing: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AtHq6La_gCehhBvv9d-TLA3wNOYG

Comment: While you have a lot of description and code in the post, but it's not [MCVE]. Consider reading how to provide [MCVE]. :)

Comment: Usually providing MCVE helps you to find the problem at first step. If you couldn't find the problem, it will help other users to reproduce the problem and try to solve it.

Comment: What else can i put here? winrar file of complete program?

Comment: BTW: `== true` is equal to `​` and `== false` is equal to `!`.

Comment: My computer almost fell over from just looking at the OneDrive file.  Surely the problem in this program as well.  Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.

Comment: I'm not that experienced in programming yet, but I checked it off. What will this solve?

Comment: **1)** Your `changeImage` method is a terrible way of doing what you're trying to accomplish. I know you say you're not that experienced yet, but I would advise doing it differently so you don't pick up bad programming habits. You can pass 1 single parameter (_a key 1 thru 7 for example_) into that and do everything you need to do with a `Select Case`. **2)** If you construct your own webpage using HTML, you can navigate to that once and let the browser handle the resizing using CSS...not your code. Then your `changeImage` method can just swap the img src instead of navigating.

Comment: Oke, thank you! I will try and adjust.